# Jupyter Lab Developing/Adding A Sidebar

Tags: typescript, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have been working on building a custom sidebar, and I found out this code snippet (below) on creating a simple sidebar. Please help me understand why it doesn't work and if it needs any fixes.

I am facing an error while the code compiles, where it could not find some of the 'node_modules'.

I am trying to get a basic UI and then keep adding features as I build them out. Thanks!

```
  /**
* Activate the extension.
*/
function activateext(
app: JupyterLab,
docmanager: IDocumentManager,
editorTracker: IEditorTracker,
restorer: ILayoutRestorer,
notebookTracker: INotebookTracker,
rendermime: IRenderMimeRegistry,
palette: ICommandPalette,
): IExt {
// Create the ext widget.
const ext = new Ext({docmanager, rendermime, palette});
// Create the ext registry.
const registry = new ExtRegistry();
//add commands
addCommands(app, palette);


// Add the ext to the left area.
ext.title.label = 'DTLA';
ext.id = 'table-of-contents';
app.shell.addToLeftArea(ext, {rank: 700});

// Add the ext widget to the application restorer.
restorer.add(ext, 'juputerlab-ext');

return registry;
}

export default extension;
```

I found this code snippet at [JupyterLab - add a subset of commands to sidebar tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691320/jupyterlab-add-a-subset-of-commands-to-sidebar-tab)

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what do you mean by "why the code doesn't work" so others can easily provide you help. If you receive an error, make sure to add it to the question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to add customized side-bar to the jupyter-lab (TAT). I also meet a lot of `node-modules not found` errors, and I found that there are many modules of `@jupyterLab/` not in the node_modules folder of the project I created with cookiecutter, even though these module can be found in jupyterLab.So my solution is to find those missing modules on npm and install them to the project.